# What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?

Tags: performance, rust, future

I read the [tokio documentation](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/tokio/) and I wonder what is the best approach for encapsulating costly synchronous I/O in a future.

With the reactor framework, we get the advantage of a green threading model: a few OS threads handle a lot of concurrent tasks through an executor.

The future model of tokio is demand driven, which means the future itself will poll its internal state to provide informations about its completion; allowing backpressure and cancellation capabilities. As far as I understand, the polling phase of the future must be non-blocking to work well.

The I/O I want to encapsulate can be seen as a long atomic and costly operation. Ideally, an independent task would perform the I/O and the associated future would poll the I/O thread for the completion status.

The two only options I see are:

- Include the blocking I/O in the `poll` function of the future.
- spawn an OS thread to perform the I/O and use the future mechanism to poll its state, as [shown in the documentation](https://tokio.rs/docs/going-deeper/synchronization/)

As I understand it, neither solution is optimal and don't get the full advantage of the green-threading model (first is not advised in documentation and second don't pass through the executor provided by reactor framework). Is there another solution?

Comment: Option 3: Let the long running operation run on a threadpool, which signals a future (that is polled from the IO thread) upon completion. Afaik tokio already has support for this with some kind of ThreadPool executor (instead of the IO executor).

Comment: Further to @Matthias247's comment, the crate for running futures on a thread pool is [`futures-cpupool`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs/tree/master/futures-cpupool).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Ideally, an independent task would perform the I/O and the associated future would poll the I/O thread for the completion status.

Yes, this is the recommended approach for asynchronous execution. Note that this is **not restricted to I/O**, but is valid for *any* long-running synchronous task!

## Futures crate

The [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/executor/struct.ThreadPool.html) type was created for this<sup>1</sup>.

In this case, you spawn work to run in the pool. The pool itself performs the work to check to see if the work is completed yet and returns a type that fulfills the `Future` trait.

```
use futures::{
    executor::{self, ThreadPool},
    future,
    task::{SpawnError, SpawnExt},
}; // 0.3.1, features = ["thread-pool"]
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

async fn delay_for(pool: &ThreadPool, seconds: u64) -> Result<u64, SpawnError> {
    pool.spawn_with_handle(async {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(3));
        3
    })?
    .await;
    Ok(seconds)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), SpawnError> {
    let pool = ThreadPool::new().expect("Unable to create threadpool");

    let a = delay_for(&pool, 3);
    let b = delay_for(&pool, 1);

    let c = executor::block_on(async {
        let (a, b) = future::join(a, b).await;

        Ok(a? + b?)
    });

    println!("{}", c?);
    Ok(())
}
```

You can see that the total time is only 3 seconds:

```
% time ./target/debug/example
4

real    3.010
user    0.002
sys     0.003
```

**1** — There's some [discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/issues/1517#issuecomment-498983558) that the current implementation may not be the *best* for blocking operations, but it suffices for now.

## Tokio

Here, we use `task::spawn_blocking`

```
use futures::future; // 0.3.15
use std::{thread, time::Duration};
use tokio::task; // 1.7.1, features = ["full"]

async fn delay_for(seconds: u64) -> Result<u64, task::JoinError> {
    task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(seconds));
        seconds
    })
    .await?;
    Ok(seconds)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), task::JoinError> {
    let a = delay_for(3);
    let b = delay_for(1);

    let (a, b) = future::join(a, b).await;
    let c = a? + b?;

    println!("{}", c);

    Ok(())
}
```

See also [CPU-bound tasks and blocking code](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.7.1/tokio/#cpu-bound-tasks-and-blocking-code) in the Tokio documentation.

## Additional points

Note that this is **not** an efficient way of sleeping, it's just a placeholder for some blocking operation. If you actually need to sleep, use something like [futures-timer](https://crates.io/crates/futures-timer) or [`tokio::time::sleep`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.7.1/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html). See [Why does Future::select choose the future with a longer sleep period first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48735952/155423) for more details

> neither solution is optimal and don't get the full advantage of the green-threading model

That's correct - because you don't have something that is asynchronous! You are trying to combine two different methodologies and there has to be an ugly bit *somewhere* to translate between them.

> second don't pass through the executor provided by reactor framework

I'm not sure what you mean here. There's an executor implicitly created by `block_on` or `tokio::main`. The thread pool has some internal logic that checks to see if a thread is done, but that should only be triggered when the user's executor `poll`s it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By executor I  meant the [Core event loop](https://tokio.rs/docs/getting-started/reactor/) which basically do not spawn any thread if I get it right.
Although I think I begin to get my mind around this: the Core event loop and cpu pool executors are complementary things, the most efficient depends on the situation (core event loop for low level rapid polling -like OS socket polling- and cpu-pool for heavy IO like network or disks)