# How do I execute an async/await function without using any external dependencies?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

I am attempting to create simplest possible example that can get `async fn hello()` to eventually print out `Hello World!`. This should happen without any external dependency like `tokio`, just plain Rust and `std`. Bonus points if we can get it done without ever using `unsafe`.

```
#![feature(async_await)]

async fn hello() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}

fn main() {
    let task = hello();

    // Something beautiful happens here, and `Hello, World!` is printed on screen.
}
```

- I know `async/await` is still a nightly feature, and it is subject to change in the foreseeable future.
- I know there is a whole lot of `Future` implementations, I am aware of the existence of `tokio`.
- I am just trying to educate myself on the inner workings of standard library futures.

#### My helpless, clumsy endeavours

My vague understanding is that, first off, I need to `Pin` task down. So I went ahead and

```
let pinned_task = Pin::new(&mut task);
```

but

```
the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:7:18: 9:2 {}]>`
```

so I thought, of course, I probably need to `Box` it, so I'm sure it won't move around in memory. Somewhat surprisingly, I get the same error.

What I could get so far is

```
let pinned_task = unsafe {
    Pin::new_unchecked(&mut task)
};
```

which is obviously not something I should do. Even so, let's say I got my hands on the `Pin`ned `Future`. Now I need to `poll()` it somehow. For that, I need a `Waker`.

So I tried to look around on how to get my hands on a `Waker`. On the [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.Waker.html) it kinda looks like the only way to get a `Waker` is with another `new_unchecked` that accepts a `RawWaker`. From there I got [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.RawWaker.html) and from there [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.RawWakerVTable.html), where I just curled up on the floor and started crying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This part of the futures stack is not *intended* to be implemented by many people. The rough estimate that I have seen in that maybe there will be 10 or so actual implementations.

That said, you can fill in the basic aspects of an executor that is extremely limited by following the function signatures needed:

```
async fn hello() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}

fn main() {
    drive_to_completion(hello());
}

use std::{
    future::Future,
    ptr,
    task::{Context, Poll, RawWaker, RawWakerVTable, Waker},
};

fn drive_to_completion<F>(f: F) -> F::Output
where
    F: Future,
{
    let waker = my_waker();
    let mut context = Context::from_waker(&waker);

    let mut t = Box::pin(f);
    let t = t.as_mut();

    loop {
        match t.poll(&mut context) {
            Poll::Ready(v) => return v,
            Poll::Pending => panic!("This executor does not support futures that are not ready"),
        }
    }
}

type WakerData = *const ();

unsafe fn clone(_: WakerData) -> RawWaker {
    my_raw_waker()
}
unsafe fn wake(_: WakerData) {}
unsafe fn wake_by_ref(_: WakerData) {}
unsafe fn drop(_: WakerData) {}

static MY_VTABLE: RawWakerVTable = RawWakerVTable::new(clone, wake, wake_by_ref, drop);

fn my_raw_waker() -> RawWaker {
    RawWaker::new(ptr::null(), &MY_VTABLE)
}

fn my_waker() -> Waker {
    unsafe { Waker::from_raw(my_raw_waker()) }
}
```

Starting at [`Future::poll`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll), we see we need a [`Pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/pin/struct.Pin.html)ned future and a [`Context`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/task/struct.Context.html). `Context` is created from a [`Waker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/task/struct.Waker.html) which needs a [`RawWaker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/task/struct.RawWaker.html). A `RawWaker` needs a [`RawWakerVTable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/task/struct.RawWakerVTable.html). We create all of those pieces in the simplest possible ways:

- Since we aren't trying to support `NotReady` cases, we never need to actually do anything for that case and can instead panic. This also means that the implementations of `wake` can be no-ops.
- Since we aren't trying to be efficient, we don't need to store any data for our waker, so `clone` and `drop` can basically be no-ops as well.
- The easiest way to pin the future is to `Box` it, but this isn't the most efficient possibility.

---

If you wanted to support `NotReady`, the simplest extension is to have a busy loop, polling forever. A slightly more efficient solution is to have a global variable that indicates that someone has called `wake` and block on that becoming true.

Comment: Amazing! Minor question: what's still in nightly is the `async/await` feature (hence the `#![feature(async_await)]`), but the `std::Future` interface is now stable, right?

Comment: @MatteoMonti kind of? `Future` has been stabilized in the nightly compiler, but that stabilization has not yet made it to the beta channel. It definitely hasn't made it to any released Rust version.

Comment: @MatteoMonti `Future` will be stabilized (in 1.36.0), but not in the current stable (1.34.0). You need the feature fo `async fn hellow`.

Comment: this is exactly what we needed to use an async function in a sync FFI. thanks!