# Streamed upload to s3 with rusoto

Tags: rust, rusoto

How can I upload file to s3 using [rusoto](https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto), without reading file content to memory (streamed)?

---

With this code:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;

use rusoto_core::Region;
use rusoto_s3::{PutObjectRequest, S3, S3Client, StreamingBody};

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("input.txt").unwrap();
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let s3_client = S3Client::new(Region::UsEast1);
    let result = s3_client.put_object(PutObjectRequest {
        bucket: String::from("example_bucket"),
        key: "example_filename".to_string(),
//        this works:
//      body: Some("example string".to_owned().into_bytes().into()),
//        this doesn't:
        body: Some(StreamingBody::new(reader)),
        ..Default::default()
    }).sync().expect("could not upload");
}
```

I receive the following error:

> ```
> error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>: futures::stream::Stream` is not satisfied
>   --> src/bin/example.rs:18:20
>    |
> 18 |         body: Some(StreamingBody::new(reader)),
>    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures::stream::Stream` is not implemented for `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>`
>    |
>    = note: required by `rusoto_core::stream::ByteStream::new`
> ```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Okay. Strap yourself in, this is a fun one.

`StreamingBody` is an alias for [`ByteStream`](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html), which itself takes a parameter type `S: Stream<Item = Bytes, Error = Error> + Send + 'static`. In short, it needs to be a stream of bytes.

[`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html), evidently, does not implement this trait, as it predates futures and streams by a long while. There is also no easy conversion to `Stream<Item = Bytes>` that you can use to implicitly convert into this.

The reason the first (commented) example works is because `String::into_bytes().into()` will follow the typecast chain: `String` -> `Vec<u8>` -> `ByteStream` thanks to the implementation of `From<Vec<u8>>` on [`ByteStream`](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html).

Now that we know why this doesn't work, we can fix it. There is a fast way, and then there is a right way. I'll show you both.

## The fast way

The fast (but not optimal) way is simply to call `File::read_to_end()`. This will fill up a `Vec<u8>`, which you can then use like you did before:

```
 let mut buf:Vec<u8> = vec![];
 file.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
 // buf now contains the entire file
```

This is inefficient and suboptimal for two reasons:

- `read_to_end()` is a blocking call. Based on where you are reading the file from, this blocking time may prove unreasonable
- You are required to have more free RAM than you have bytes in your file (+ either 64 or 128 bits for the `Vec` definition + some extra we don't really care about)

## The good way

The good way turns your file into a structure implementing [`AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.20/tokio/prelude/trait.AsyncRead.html). From this, we can then form a `Stream`.

Since you already have a `std::fs::File`, we will first convert it into a `tokio::fs::File`. This implements `AsyncRead`, which is very important for later:

```
let tokio_file = tokio::fs::File::from_std(file);
```

From this, we sadly need to do some pipework to get it into a `Stream`. Multiple crates have implemented it; the way to do so from scratch is the following:

```
use tokio_util::codec;
let byte_stream = codec::FramedRead::new(tokio_file, codec::BytesCodec::new())
   .map(|r| r.as_ref().to_vec());
```

`byte_stream` is an instance of `tokio_util::codec::FramedRead` which [implements `Stream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.3.1/tokio_util/codec/struct.FramedRead.html#impl-Stream) with a specific item based on our decoder. As our decoder is [`BytesCodec`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.3.1/tokio_util/codec/struct.BytesCodec.html), your stream is therefore `Stream<Item = BytesMut>`.

As the playground doesn't know `rusoto_core`, I cannot show you the full flow. I can, however, show you that you can generate a `Stream<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = io::Error>`, which is the crux of this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=38e4ae8be0d70abd134b5331d6bf4133

Comment: Thanks! I just have to replace `.map(|r| r.as_ref().to_vec())` to `.map(|r| r.freeze())`, because `rusoto` need `impl Stream<Item = Bytes>` (not `impl Stream<Item = Vec<u8>>`) ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b81ff36d7acaa63b48d87364e1f11fa))

Comment: Glad it helped :-) I wasn't sure from the doc, so I went with the extra-crate-less possible choice

Answer (score 7):

Here's a version with the upcoming Rusoto async-await syntax (for getObject although should be straightforward to tweak for upload)... possibly out for public consumption in Rusoto 0.4.3:

https://github.com/brainstorm/rusoto-s3-async-await

Namely:

```rust
pub async fn bucket_obj_bytes(client: S3Client, bucket: String, _prefix: String, object: String) {
    let get_req = GetObjectRequest {
        bucket,
        key: object,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let result = client
        .get_object(get_req)
        .await
        .expect("Couldn't GET object");
    println!("get object result: {:#?}", result);

    let stream = result.body.unwrap();
    let body = stream.map_ok(|b| BytesMut::from(&b[..])).try_concat().await.unwrap();

    assert!(body.len() > 0);
    dbg!(body);
}
```

Which is essentially borrowed from the [integration testsuite itself](https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto/blob/6365d2cc9c5c3c98a6ef455275ac50772f49dc19/integration_tests/tests/s3.rs#L887), where you can find [snippets of the upload version too](https://github.com/rusoto/rusoto/blob/6365d2cc9c5c3c98a6ef455275ac50772f49dc19/integration_tests/tests/s3.rs#L625).

Comment: To anybody reading this, please switch over to https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-rust instead, Rusoto is dead.