# Upload AsyncRead to s3 rust

Tags: amazon-s3, rust, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-rust

I am try to upload AsyncRead trait to s3, but I can not figure out how to convert the AsyncRead object to ByteStream which the library (aws-sdk-s3) know how to work with.

The signature of my function is like this:

`async fn upload(&self, key: String, data: &mut impl AsyncRead) -> Result<(),Error>;`

```
let byte_stream = codec::FramedRead::new(read, codec::BytesCodec::new()).map(|r| r.freeze());
let res = s3
    .put_object()
    .key(id)
    .body(ByteStream::new(byte_stream))
    .send()
    .await;
```

The errors that I got are:

- the trait bound `&impl 'async_trait + AsyncRead: AsyncRead` is not satisfied
- `FramedRead<&impl 'async_trait + AsyncRead, BytesCodec>` is not an iterator

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810173/streamed-upload-to-s3-with-rusoto) and tried to implement it like the "good way" section but I got compile errors.

I also looked at the [documentation](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-s3/0.24.0/aws_sdk_s3/types/struct.ByteStream.html) and found nothing that can help with the conversion (found only the other way around).

How can I upload an AsyncRead object to s3?

Comment: Please share your attempt and compile errors.

Comment: I added the code and the error

Comment: can you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long wait for this feature. Unfortunately as of the time of writing the only way is to use a multi-part upload strategy.

Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-rust/discussions/361

And here's an example of multi-part upload where you can read your `AsyncRead` in chunks and transfer them one by one: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-rust/blob/main/examples/examples/s3/src/bin/s3-multipart-upload.rs