# What happens to an async task when it is aborted?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

Rust has `async` methods that can be tied to [`Abortable`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.19/futures/future/struct.Abortable.html) futures. The documentation says that, when aborted:

> the future will complete immediately without making any further progress.

Will the variables owned by the task bound to the future be dropped? If those variables implement `drop`, will `drop` be called? If the future has spawned other futures, will all of them be aborted in a chain?

E.g.: [In the following snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d0ffcf61c52490e447f7e8d12010f82), I don't see the *destructor* happening for the aborted task, but I don't know if it is not called or happens in a separate thread where the *print* is not shown.

```
use futures::executor::block_on;
use futures::future::{AbortHandle, Abortable};

struct S {
    i: i32,
}

impl Drop for S {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping S");
    }
}

async fn f() -> i32 {
    let s = S { i: 42 };
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(2));
    s.i
}

fn main() {
    println!("first test...");
    let (abort_handle, abort_registration) = AbortHandle::new_pair();
    let _ = Abortable::new(f(), abort_registration);
    abort_handle.abort();
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

    println!("second test...");
    let (_, abort_registration) = AbortHandle::new_pair();
    let task = Abortable::new(f(), abort_registration);
    block_on(task).unwrap();
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d0ffcf61c52490e447f7e8d12010f82)

Comment: Do **not** use blocking / thread sleeps in asynchronous code. [Why does Future::select choose the future with a longer sleep period first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48735952/155423). [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423).

Comment: In the first test, you abort the future before it is ever scheduled for execution, so it never starts → it doesn't need to call the destructor because it never allocated `s` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11622685d186eac875fdf6c35d1b8a4a))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, values that *have been created* will be dropped.

In your first example, the future returned by `f` is never started, so the `S` is never created. This means that it cannot be dropped.

In the second example, the value is dropped.

This is more obvious if you both run the future *and* abort it. Here, I spawn two concurrent futures:

1. create an `S` and waits 200ms
2. wait 100ms and abort future #1

```
use futures::future::{self, AbortHandle, Abortable};
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time;

struct S {
    i: i32,
}

impl S {
    fn new(i: i32) -> Self {
        println!("Creating S {}", i);
        S { i }
    }
}

impl Drop for S {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping S {}", self.i);
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let create_s = async {
        let s = S::new(42);
        time::delay_for(Duration::from_millis(200)).await;
        println!("Creating {} done", s.i);
    };
    let (abort_handle, abort_registration) = AbortHandle::new_pair();
    let create_s = Abortable::new(create_s, abort_registration);

    let abort_s = async move {
        time::delay_for(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        abort_handle.abort();
    };

    let c = tokio::spawn(create_s);
    let a = tokio::spawn(abort_s);

    let (c, a) = future::join(c, a).await;

    println!("{:?}, {:?}", c, a);
}
```

```
Creating S 42
Dropping S 42
Ok(Err(Aborted)), Ok(())
```

Note that I've switched to Tokio to be able to use `time::delay_for`, as you should never use blocking operations in an async function.

See also:

- [Why does Future::select choose the future with a longer sleep period first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48735952/155423)
- [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423)

> If the future has spawned other futures, will all of them be aborted in a chain?

No, when you `spawn` a future, it is disconnected from where it was spawned.

See also:

- [What is the purpose of async/await in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835725/155423)