# Is there a way to delay execution for a certain amount of time inside the body of a Rust async function?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I think `std::thread::sleep(...)` is not the right use case here.

Comment: just found [tokio_timer](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer/0.3.0-alpha.5/tokio_timer/index.html). Maybe that's what I'm looking for

Comment: If you are using aync-std, it would be [`async_std::task::sleep()`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.6.2/async_std/task/fn.sleep.html) instead.

Comment: i'm using tokio and found this: `tokio::time::delay_for(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(WAIT_TIME_INTERVAL_MS));` I think that's it.

Comment: *`std::thread::sleep(...)` is not the right use case* — You are completely correct. See [Why does Future::select choose the future with a longer sleep period first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48735952/155423)

Comment: yep, thanks @Shepmaster

Answer (score 2):

Using the  [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/time/fn.delay_for.html) crate, there exists this function

```
tokio::time::delay_for(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(WAIT_TIME_INTERVAL_MS));
```

That actually waits for `Duration` with any execution.

Comment: I think it's called `sleep` instead of `delay_for` now