# impl AsyncRead for tonic::Streaming

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio, rust-rocket

I am trying to take the tonic [routeguide tutorial](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/routeguide-tutorial.md), and turn the client into a [rocket](https://crates.io/crates/rocket) server. I am just taking the response and converting from the gRPC to a string.

```
service RouteGuide {
    rpc GetFeature(Point) returns (Feature) {}
    rpc ListFeatures(Rectangle) returns (stream Feature) {}
}
```

This works well enough for GetFeature. For the ListFeatures query, just as Tonic allows the client the stream in the response, I wanted to pass this on to the Rocket client. I see that Rocket supports [streaming](https://rocket.rs/master/guide/responses/#streaming) responses, but I need to implement the [AsyncRead](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.2.0/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html) trait.

Is there any way to do something like this? Below is a trimmed down version of about what I was doing:

```
struct FeatureStream {
    stream: tonic::Streaming<Feature>,
}

impl AsyncRead for FeatureStream {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        // Write out as utf8 any response messages.
        match Pin::new(&mut self.stream.message()).poll(cx) {
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
            Poll::Ready(feature) => Poll::Pending,
        }
    }
}

#[get("/list_features")]
async fn list_features(client: State<'_, RouteGuideClient<Channel>>) -> Stream<FeatureStream> {
    let rectangle = Rectangle {
        low: Some(Point {
            latitude: 400_000_000,
            longitude: -750_000_000,
        }),
        high: Some(Point {
            latitude: 420_000_000,
            longitude: -730_000_000,
        }),
    };
    let mut client = client.inner().clone();
    let stream = client
        .list_features(Request::new(rectangle))
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .into_inner();
    Stream::from(FeatureStream { stream })
}

#[rocket::launch]
async fn rocket() -> rocket::Rocket {
    rocket::ignite()
        .manage(
            create_route_guide_client("http://[::1]:10000")
                .await
                .unwrap(),
        )
        .mount("/", rocket::routes![list_features,])
}
```

With the error:

```
error[E0277]: `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@Streaming<Feature>::message::{closure#0} for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1, 't2> {ResumeTy, &'r mut Streaming<Feature>, [closure@Streaming<Feature>::message::{closure#0}::{closure#0}], rocket::futures::future::PollFn<[closure@Streaming<Feature>::message::{closure#0}::{closure#0}]>, ()}]>` cannot be unpinned
   --> src/web_user.rs:34:15
    |
34  |         match Pin::new(&mut self.stream.message()).poll(cx) {
    |               ^^^^^^^^ within `impl std::future::Future`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@Streaming<Feature>::message::{closure#0} for<'r, 's, 't0, 't1, 't2> {ResumeTy, &'r mut Streaming<Feature>, [closure@Streaming<Feature>::message::{closure#0}::{closure#0}], rocket::futures::future::PollFn<[closure@Streaming<Feature>::message::{closure#0}::{closure#0}]>, ()}]>`
    | 
   ::: /home/matan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tonic-0.4.0/src/codec/decode.rs:106:40
    |
106 |     pub async fn message(&mut self) -> Result<Option<T>, Status> {
    |                                        ------------------------- within this `impl std::future::Future`
    |
    = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
    = note: required by `Pin::<P>::new`
```

Comment: It looks like `message()` function is a helper to pick next message from the tonic Streaming. You don't need `message()` function to pick next message for `AsyncRead` you already have the `Stream`, you can pick the next message by yourself, here is the code https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a1637cf47eafd720470228cecd5f1dc  
 (it returns `Pending` for all cases as your code does, you can change it as you desire)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is generated `Future` from `tonic::Streaming<Feature>::message()` doesn't implement `Unpin` since it is an **async** function. Let's label this type as `MessageFuture`, you cannot pin `&mut MessageFuture` pointer **safely** because the dereferenced type `MessageFuture` doesn't implement `Unpin`.

### Why it is not safe?

From [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html), implementation of `Unpin` brings:

> Types that can be safely moved after being pinned.

It means if `T:!Unpin` then `Pin<&mut T>` is not movable, this is important because `Future`s created by async block has no `Unpin` implementation since it might hold reference of a member from itself, and if you move the `T` the pointee of this reference will also be moved, but the reference will still point the same address, to prevent this it should not be movable. Please read ["Pinning" section from async-book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html#why-pinning) to visualize the reason.

**Note:**  `T:!Unpin` means `T` is the type that has no `Unpin` implementation.

### Solution

`message()` function is helper to pick next message from the `tonic::Streaming<T>`. You don't particularly need to call `message()` to pick next element from the stream, you already have actual stream in your structure.

```rust
struct FeatureStream {stream: tonic::Streaming<Feature>}
```

You can await for the next message for `AsyncRead` like:

```rust
impl AsyncRead for FeatureStream {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {

       //it returns Pending for all cases as your code does, you can change it as you want
        match self.stream.poll_next_unpin(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(m))) => Poll::Pending,
            Poll::Ready(Some(Err(e))) => Poll::Pending,
            Poll::Ready(None) => Poll::Pending,
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that `tonic::Streaming<T>` has implementation of `Unpin`([reference](https://docs.rs/tonic/0.4.0/tonic/struct.Streaming.html#trait-implementations))

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Omer Erden for answering this. So it came down to implementing AsyncRead based on the futures::Stream trait, which tonic::Streaming implements. Here is the code I actually used.

```
impl AsyncRead for FeatureStream {
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        use futures::stream::StreamExt;
        use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};

        match self.stream.poll_next_unpin(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(m))) => {
                buf.put_slice(format!("{:?}\n", m).as_bytes());
                Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
            }
            Poll::Ready(Some(Err(e))) => {
                Poll::Ready(Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, format!("{:?}", e))))
            }
            Poll::Ready(None) => {
                // None from a stream means the stream terminated. To indicate
                // that from AsyncRead we return Ok and leave buf unchanged.
                Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
            }
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
        }
    }
}
```

In the meantime my workaround was to create both ends of a TcpStream (which implements AsyncRead) and return one end of it while spawning a separate task to actually write out the results.

```
#[get("/list_features")]
async fn list_features(
    client: State<'_, RouteGuideClient<Channel>>,
    tasks: State<'_, Mutex<Vec<tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>>>>,
) -> Result<Stream<TcpStream>, Debug<std::io::Error>> {
    let mut client = client.inner().clone();
    let mut feature_stream = client
        .list_features(Request::new(Rectangle {
            low: Some(Point {
                latitude: 400000000,
                longitude: -750000000,
            }),
            high: Some(Point {
                latitude: 420000000,
                longitude: -730000000,
            }),
        }))
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .into_inner();

    // Port 0 tells to operating system to choose an unused port.
    let tcp_listener = TcpListener::bind(("127.0.0.1", 0)).await?;
    let socket_addr = tcp_listener.local_addr().unwrap();
    tasks.lock().unwrap().push(tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut tcp_stream = TcpStream::connect(socket_addr).await.unwrap();

        while let Some(feature) = feature_stream.message().await.unwrap() {
            match tcp_stream
                .write_all(format!("{:?}\n", feature).as_bytes())
                .await
            {
                Ok(()) => (),
                Err(e) => panic!(e),
            }
        }
        println!("End task");
        ()
    }));
    Ok(Stream::from(tcp_listener.accept().await?.0))
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't run blocking code while polling, instead you can use tokio timer to create proper delay, more information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735952/why-does-futureselect-choose-the-future-with-a-longer-sleep-period-first

Comment: I assume you are referring to the sleep that I had? That was from a test I was running and forgot to take that out when posting here, thanks for pointing it out and for pasting that link.