# Is there any point in async file IO?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, concurrency, rust-tokio

Async runtimes for Rust like *tokio* provide "asyncified" copies of many standard functions, including some file IO ones, which work by basically just summoning the corresponding blocking task (on a new thread?). Examples of such functions are `tokio::fs::create_dir_all`, `tokio::fs::read_dir`, `tokio::fs::read`, ...

**What's the advantage of all these functions?** Why should I prefer using them over standard blocking functions in async context? If I'm `.await`ing for their results, is there any gain at all?

An example would be an async web route that returns the contents of some file based on the query (using *Rocket*):

```rust
#[get("/foo/<query>")]
async fn foo(query: &str) -> Option<String> {
    let file_path = // interpret `query` somehow and find the target file
    tokio::fs::read_to_string(file_path).await.ok()
    // ^ Why not just `std::fs::read_to_string(file_path).ok()`?
}
```

I understand the gains of `async/.await` for socket IO or delayed tasks (with thread sleep), but in this case it seems pointless to me. But the opposite — this makes more complex tasks much more difficult to solve in code (working with streams when searching a file in a list of directories, for example).

Comment: Yes, because if there are any other concurrent tasks, `.await` allows them to run while the other thread with the file IO on it is blocked. Using blocking calls in an `async` task will block the thread, thus blocking *all* tasks that are running on the same thread.

Comment: Doesn't `.await` only allow other tasks to run if the task being awaited returned the `Pending` state last time it was polled by the executor? From what I understood from the async book, this is only returned when the task is not ready to produce any output yet, which is never the case for file IO (because the task *is* always ready to return some bytes, unlike, say, socket IO, whose tasks are often just waiting for new connections). If this is correct then file IO tasks never return `Pending`, and are almost the same as their blocking counterparts.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why does Future::select choose the future with a longer sleep period first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48735952/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: `std::fs::read_to_string` will **block** the thread, preventing Tokio (or any other async runtime) from running any other asynchronous tasks. If you don't want to do other things while performing IO, you don't need to use async in the first place.

Comment: *"which is never the case for file IO  - because the task is always ready to return some bytes"* - this is categorically false, while the data *may* be available immediately (particularly if the file has been read recently and still in the OS caches), most file reads will take some non-negligible amount of time, time which can be better spent doing other stuff instead of waiting around. Consider the timing of hard drive spin-up, network drives, virtual filesystems, and large reads.

Comment: *because the task is always ready to return some bytes...* - This is only true if you naively attempt to query the file descriptor using `epoll()` or the like. The fact that the file descriptor is "ready" doesn't mean that reading from it won't block for the duration it takes to read the contents from disk (or, in case of network-mounted file system, from the network, which may take an arbitrary time or never finish). The async versions of `std::fs` operations resolve that by off-loading the blocking operations to a separate thread and arranging for wakeup when the whole operation is complete.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for correcting me, I didn't know about such delays. Does this mean that thread pools are generally a better choice than async/await when writing a mostly file-I/O-bound web-server though (say, a file synchronization server)? If I now understand this correctly, async just shifts the I/O tasks to other ("non-http-server"?) threads to keep accepting new connections. If this is correct, then it doesn't seem much different from processing requests in a thread pool. And if so, when should I prefer async (when will it give some real significant advantage)? Should this be a post edit?

Comment: Honestly, for a file server where you're just shuffling bytes around 90% of the time, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: FWIW on Linux, reads from disk files always block and always report that IO is ready when using select/poll interfaces, which is what most async libraries do. So async won't really help when doing disk file IO unless the library is using the aio interface or from another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're reading a small files on a local filesystem with a pretty fast drive. If that's the case, there may be little point in using the `async` version of these functions.

If half of your HTTP requests need to read from the filesystem, then you might start noticing a substantial time where your runtime if waiting for blocking IO. This really depend on the nature of your application. Maybe you have one thread? Maybe you have many?

However, there's edge-case scenarios where filesystem can be slow enough to be a really big problem. Here's two extreme corner cases:

- A network mounted filesystem (e.g.: NFS, ipfs). There can be multiple network round-trips under `create_dir_all`. While that's blocking, your service is basically non-responsive.
- Slow hard drive. Spinning disks. Or even reading from a CD-ROM drive. Sure, you won't run your web server from a CD-ROM, but a tool that compares whether two magnetic tapes (yes, physical tapes are still used for backups) are identical would suffer greatly if some underlying library is doing blocking IO.

Now, if you're writing a library that exposes an `async` API, you can't make assumptions about the underlying filesystem or its backing hardware, and **should** use non-blocking IO.

Answer (score 18):

The difference between `tokio::fs::read_to_string` and `std::fs::read_to_string` is that the Tokio function will offload the file IO call to the `spawn_blocking` threadpool, whereas the `std::fs::read_to_string` call will not do that.

This is important because if you don't offload the file IO to a separate thread, then you are [blocking the runtime](https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/) from making progress, which means that other tasks in the runtime will be unable to execute for the duration of your file IO operation. See the link for more a in-depth explanation.