# How to read subprocess output asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, rust, stdio, rust-tokio

I want to implement a `futures::Stream` for reading and parsing the standard output of a child subprocess.

What I'm doing at the moment:

- spawn subprocess and obtain its stdout via `std::process` methods: `let child = Command::new(...).stdout(Stdio.pipe()).spawn().expect(...)`
- add `AsyncRead` and `BufRead` to stdout:

  ```
  let stdout = BufReader::new(tokio_io::io::AllowStdIo::new(
      child.stdout.expect("Failed to open stdout"),
  ));
  ```
- declare a wrapper struct for stdout:

  ```
  struct MyStream<Io: AsyncRead + BufRead> {
      io: Io,
  }
  ```
- implement `Stream`:

  ```
  impl<Io: AsyncRead + BufRead> Stream for MyStream<Io> {
      type Item = Message;
      type Error = Error;

      fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Message>, Error> {
          let mut line = String::new();
          let n = try_nb!(self.io.read_line(&mut line));
          if n == 0 {
              return Ok(None.into());
          }
          //...read & parse further
      }
  }
  ```

The problem is that `AllowStdIo` doesn't make `ChildStdout` magically asynchronous and the `self.io.read_line` call still blocks.

I guess I need to pass something different instead of `Stdio::pipe()` to have it asynchronous, but what? Or is there a different solution for that?

This question is different from [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932137/what-is-the-best-approach-to-encapsulate-blocking-i-o-in-future-rs) because I  want to get asynchronous I/O for the specific case of a subprocess and not solve the problem of encapsulation of synchronous I/O.

Update: I'm using `tokio = "0.1.3"` to leverage its runtime feature and using `tokio-process` is not an option at the moment (https://github.com/alexcrichton/tokio-process/issues/27)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version using tokio::process

```
let mut child = match Command::new(&args.run[0])
        .args(parameters)
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .kill_on_drop(true)
        .spawn() 
    {
        Ok(c) => c,
        Err(e) => panic!("Unable to start process `{}`. {}", args.run[0], e),
    };

    let stdout = child.stdout.take().expect("child did not have a handle to stdout");
    let stderr = child.stderr.take().expect("child did not have a handle to stderr");

    let mut stdout_reader = BufReader::new(stdout).lines();
    let mut stderr_reader = BufReader::new(stderr).lines();

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            result = stdout_reader.next_line() => {
                match result {
                    Ok(Some(line)) => println!("Stdout: {}", line),
                    Err(_) => break,
                    _ => (),
                }
            }
            result = stderr_reader.next_line() => {
                match result {
                    Ok(Some(line)) => println!("Stderr: {}", line),
                    Err(_) => break,
                    _ => (),
                }
            }
            result = child.wait() => {
                match result {
                    Ok(exit_code) => println!("Child process exited with {}", exit_code),
                    _ => (),
                }
                break // child process exited
            }
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`tokio-process`](https://docs.rs/tokio-process/latest/tokio_process/) crate provides you with a `CommandExt` trait that allows you to spawn a command asynchronously.

The resulting `Child` has a getter for `ChildStdout` which implements `Read` and is non-blocking.

Wrapping `tokio_process::ChildStdout` into `AllowStdIo` as you did in your example should make it work!

**2023 Update**

`tokio-process::CommandExt` has been deprecated in favor of [`tokio::process::Command`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/process/index.html) which you can use in a relatively similar way.

Comment: Thanks! I think it will not work well with new tokio yet (https://github.com/alexcrichton/tokio-process/issues/27) which I want to use to leverage its runtime feature. I'll update my question with that clarification.