# Using std::sync::Mutex from asynchronous Tokio code

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I am implementing a feature using the async/await based Tokio and Rust 1.39.0. I understand there can be performance implications with using the regular `Mutex` from within an async context, but are there any other possible effects? For example, I remember reading somewhere it can lock up the thread pool/runtime or hang the system.

For context, the rest of our system is written in a synchronous way. I am looking at implementing the network facing part using the latest Tokio which would use `tokio::sync::Mutex` and friends. It is possible that the asynchronous network component calls into the synchronous parts which try to take the `sync::Mutex`.

Some options:

1. Separate these parts via message passing
2. Change parts of the rest of the system to be async aware, which would be a big undertaking.

I would like to avoid both if possible.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Thanks for the link,  gives a good background. That discussion focuses on blocking for a long running operation. My case is little different, but still about blocking: blocking on sync locks. The code is designed to hold these for minimal time(e.g) update a HashMap under lock.

Comment: So IIUC, if we make sure the per-CPU executor threads don't block(or block for short/reasonable duration), we should be fine. Does this assertion sound right?