# What is the best way to spawn a thread and obtain the result as a future?

Tags: multithreading, rust, future

Is there a better way to do something like below?

```rust
use futures::channel::oneshot; // 0.3.4
use std::thread;

pub async fn spawn<Y>(f: impl Fn() -> Y + Send + Sync + 'static) -> Y
where
    Y: Send + 'static,
{
    let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel::<Y>();
    thread::spawn(move || sender.send(f()));
    receiver.await.unwrap()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks. ```tokio::task::spawn_blocking``` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate of [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932137/what-is-the-best-approach-to-encapsulate-blocking-i-o-in-future-rs)

Answer (score 0):

`tokio::task::spawn_blocking` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions. Instead, you can choose to mark them as duplicates (we have already done so at this point).